# DevicePolicyManager.lockNow() in SystemUI quick settings using custom ROM

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-source, android-settings, custom-rom

I am starting with learning and customizing SystemUI of AOSP.

I was wondering how to implement `lockNow()` feature on click of an icon.

I have added that icon in `qs_panel.xml` layout and trying to get that working on  `QSFragment.java`.

I know how to do in normal apps but not able to achieve it in SystemUI app.

If I directly call `DevicePolicyManager.lockNow(0);` then it raises exception

```
java.lang.SecurityException: No active admin owned by uid 10036 for policy #3
```

now this exception means that the module shall act like admin in order to do so.

**Ques:** How to define policies for `SystemUI module` so that I can use `DevicePolicyManager.lockNow()` to get what I need.

Any help!!